# Page for 404 error in .htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I've created a static page for 404 and added the below code in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

**ErrorDocument 404 PageNotFound.php**
```

When i tried to open a non existing page by entering a wrong text in the url, the page for 404 is not showing instead it is showing the file name of the page, not the content, just like

> PageNotFound.php

Both the page not found static page and .htaccess file are in root folder. What could be the reason for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `errordocument` destination is wrong. You need to add a `/` before  the target filename otherwise the target file is treated as a string and the server appends it to the  current page.

Change your ErrorDocument to this

```
ErrorDocument 404 /PageNotFound.php
```

Comment: Thank you. But when i changed as above it shows a Not found error with "Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

But actually the PageNotFound.php exists in the root folder. Both .htaccess file and PageNotFound.php is in the same folder.

Comment: Do you have any others rules or redirects in the htaccess file?

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 404 /PageNotFound.php`



This is my code in htaccess file. Thanks..

Comment: There is rewriting rule for removing file extension other than ErrorDocument 404 /PageNotFound.php in htaccess file.